# auto add variable in template

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I added mydata in setup function of the BaseView.

> ```
> class BaseView(View):
>
> def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>     super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     self.mydata = table.objects.all()
> ```

When I print it in the get function of child class, the value is correct but I'd like this variable be added in template file automatically.

> ```
> def get(self, request, pk=''):
>
> print('self.active_apps in plan')
>     print(self.active_apps)
>     user_info = request.session.get('user_info')
>     context = {'user_info':user_info}
>     if pk != '':
>         item = get_object_or_404(self.model_class, pk=pk)
>         form = self.form_class(instance=item)
>         context['form'] = form
>         context['pk'] = pk
>     else:
>         form = self.form_class()
>         context['form'] = form
>
>     return render(request, self.template_name, context)
> ```

Comment: It is a bit odd to use `View`, usually you use a class-based view like a `TemplateView`, `FormView`, and here likely `UpdateVIew`, this will then automate a lot of the data and thus make it easy to work with such `Setup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably *not* adding this in views, but a [*context processor* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

We can define such context processor like:

```
# my_app/context_processors.py


def table_data(request):
    return {'my_data': table.objects.all()}
```

and then register the context processor in the `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'OPTIONS': {
            # …,
            'context_processors': [
                # …,
                'my_app.context_processors.table_data'
            ]
        },
    }
]
```

This will, each time you render a template with this backend, run the context processors to populate the context further.

Since querysets are lazy, it will also not make an requests if the template does not "consume" the `my_data`. But now if we thus render a template, we can enumerate over `my_data`.